# Is there a way to run yarn test (jest) and directly update interactively?

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg

Here's the current situation:
Whenever we push the code to our build servers, the tests are run on those servers.
When tests fail I have a list of failed tests I need to fix and it would be a timesaver if instead of running `yarn test` then proceed through the options by choosing "run all tests" and "i update interactively" to just go to that interactive update directly.

I've looked through some of the jest documentation, but couldn't find a clear answer whether it's possible to start it directly. For example by doing something like `yarn test -update -interactive` (made up parameters as example).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the watch mode

```
yarn run test --watch
```

For integration with commit and push you need to create git hooks, you may have a look at husky

```
{
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn test -u -t="your test title goes here" --watch",
      "pre-push": "yarn test",
      "...": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that one exists, but I don't want to continuously check for changes. Ideally I want to do this once at the end of my workflow, right before checking in my work.